# Mixitup JQuery custom filters and sort

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this awesome JQuery plugin for ecommerce. I want to make one filter for price, like 0-25€, 25-50€ and a sort option for order by date added.

Someone can help me with this? I don't need the filters done but where should I modify the Mixitup code to make this happen.

Thanks!

***EDIT***

I couldn't make this happen, so I did this in the server.

Comment: there is no reference to any code, link to code or any way for anyone to have any idea what code you are using. Need to be far more specific in questions

Comment: Mixitup Jquery plugin... But anyway i finished using server code and not modifing this PLUGIN. thanks

Comment: be more specific when asking questions next time. There are 1000's of plugin and just giving a name does little

Comment: Ok, but there is just one mixitup jquery plugin. You must be more specific on reading the questions...

Comment: NO...you be specific and procvide doc links. People won;t go googling trying to figure out what you are using. Remember people help here of their own time. Guidleines for asking questions are very clear

Comment: NO... if I say I'm using mixitup is clear enough, if you don't know what it's that you can google it or just ask me, but you can't say "there is no reference to any code, link to code or any way for anyone to have any idea what code you are using. Need to be far more specific in questions" because it was clear, MIXITUP JQUERY PLUGIN

Comment: give it a rest...and if you want to play nice in the sandbox read about asking proper questions in FAQ. People will help...if they are given details

Comment: I want to thank you for all the questions that you answered, but I can not copy paste mixitup... I said what I'm using, I think is enough, maybe a link for the code... Thanks again, but you were wrong with you answer: "any way for anyone to have any idea what code you are using"........ no, no this time